# Is there a captureNetworkTraffic implementation in Selenium 2 via webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium2, webdriver

If yes, how is it called, or where can I find more info about it? (I'm not talking about using WebDriverBackend.)

If not, what alternatives are there?

Comment: I may eventually do that, but rather look for native webdriver solutions.

Comment: Question has been answered, but many people on SQA cannot find answer to this problem, and are duplicating the question. Could we add more context to the question regarding the problem. For instance, this [http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/how-can-i-automate-testing-of-http-requests](duplicate question) describes it very clearly and from more general perspective, IMHO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can capture network traffic using a proxy, such as the BrowserMob Proxy (http://proxy.browsermob.com)

To configure the use of the proxy with a webdriver instance, set the CapabilityName.PROXY value to a org.openqa.selenium.Proxy instance:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
// The URL here is the URL that the browsermob proxy is using
proxy.setHttpProxy("localhost:9100");

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Once the test is finished, you can extract the data from the browsermob proxy using the mechanisms it provides. Notice that you can also use any proxy you want: it need not be the browsermob one!

Comment: Does using a proxy slow down the test?

Comment: and then how do you check the value from the proxy in the test? ...yet another whole system to maintain and to add false positives.

Answer (score 4):

No there is no native solution at the moment.  If you use webDriverBackedSelenium you can try to utilise the captureNetworkTraffic functionality, however there were issues with it last time I heard it talked about  (See here for more info - https://groups.google.com/d/topic/selenium-users/fMSHeH9ZVqU/discussion).

It's also worth noting that captureNetworkTraffic only works in FireFox due to the way it was implemented so it's not a cross browser solution.

***Update***

Based on some information that came through the selenium/webdriver mailing lists you can use a proxy instead (Suggested one is http://bmp.lightbody.net/, although there are others).

To configure it:

```
 Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
 proxy.setHttpProxy(<proxyAddress>);
 DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
 cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
```

This should currently work for FireFox and IE.  It looks like this is going to be the way to capture network traffic moving forward.

Note: "new Proxy()" - Needs org.openqa.selenium.Proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a combination of Charles Proxy and `window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource')` inside an `executeScript`. Performance does not capture POST data, so that is why I also use Charles. I export the Charles session as a .har file and then use a nodejs script to merge the data.

Collect window performance data, filtered to get Adobe Analytics ("b/ss"), and then just returning the name aka the GET or POST url string .

```
let getPerformance = () => {
    return  (window.performance.getEntriesByType('resource').filter(function(entry){
        return /b\/ss/i.test(entry.name);
    })).map( entry => { return decodeURIComponent(entry.name) }).join("\n");
}

driver.executeScript( getPerformance ).then( windowPerformance => { /* do something with window.performance data */ })
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked through it all yet, but I did find a [post](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2010/client-side-profiling-with-selenium-2.html) that seems related.  Also, haven't tried it out, but, have you looked at any of the fiddler libraries?  Although I have plans on trying them out, it's not going to be for a few months yet.

Comment: Looks interesting, but I'm looking for a more complete solutions, maybe requiring the usage of two tools (like selenium and gson, in my case). This looks like a lot of work to accomplish this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can automate it using BrowserMob Proxy.
[Please use the below mentioedn link to test Network traffic using BrowserMob Proxy

https://keshavtechinfo.wordpress.com/web-automation/selenium/web-page-load-testing-using-selenium-and-browsermob-proxy/
][1](https://keshavtechinfo.wordpress.com/web-automation/selenium/web-page-load-testing-using-selenium-and-browsermob-proxy/)

Comment: How about writing the answer here and using the link as reference?

Comment: Using BrowserMob Proxy, we capture performance data 
How to use BrowserMob Proxy?
Download BrowserMob Proxy
2.Start BrowserMob Proxy
Create a new Project and import BrowserMob Proxy with Selenium Standalone Server Jar
Run the script.
After running the script, you will see the proxy server is started, and respective logs are generated.
As the script stops, an HTTP achieve file is also generated with Performance Log of the desired web application.
Now you can import that HAR file and see the results at http://pcapperf.appspot.com/. It will show the fetched performance data.