# How can I automate testing of HTTP requests?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a captureNetworkTraffic implementation in Selenium 2 via webdriver?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/is-there-a-capturenetworktraffic-implementation-in-selenium-2-via-webdriver)

I'm using Selenium2/C# to run automated tests of a web app. I need to test the HTTP requests sent with each interaction with the UI. I use Charles to manually view the requests but how can I automate those tests? I'm not a very experienced programmer so I'm not sure - is there a way to do this just using C# to get the HTTP requests that are sent as my Selenium tests are running, or do I need some additional tool/library etc.?

I've looked at the Webdriver documentation and can't see anything there.

Comment: Thanks. I did search but didn't spot that question. I'll take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: I've finally had time to try this and it worked. Also I found a very useful .Net library for working with Selenium and BrowserMob proxy by Adrian Hills and David Burns here: [AdaTheDev](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2012/02/automating-web-performance-stats.html)