# How to use selenium.captureNetworkTraffic in Python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, http

I'm interested in debugging my browser session and I found that it is possible to save HTTP requests with their answers to a file using `captureNetworkTraffic` in `json` format.

But I can't find any doc or working samples to do so. The only thing I found that `selenium.selenium` is a part v.1 API, in the current version (v.2) I should use `webdriver`. `webdriver` API doesn't have `captureNetworkTraffic` option or something like this.

I've found a [java sample](http://blog.eviltester.com/2010/05/a-selenium-capturenetworktraffic-example-in-java.html) but it is too old (maybe v.1 used) and it requires to run some server. Another [one sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712278/selenium-rc-how-do-you-use-capturenetworktraffic-in-python#) doesn't work for me - I receive `error: [Errno 111] Connection refused` and I don't understand it. What selenium should be connected to on `localhost:4444`? The server mentioned in the first sample?

I've tried to do a hack `driver.execute("captureNetworkTraffic", {"type":"json"})`, but it doesn't work either. Also I can't find a string `captureNetworkTraffic` in chromedriver's sources.

So, is it possible to dump requests and responses without [using proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075645/export-har-using-chromedriver)?

Comment: Dup of http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5090/selenium-monitor-network-capturenetworktraffic-command-not-available?

Comment: May be... I can't catch what is Selenium RC.