# Accessing weblogs via Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

I am using Selenium via Java.

I am trying to test third party tracking and I am wondering if there is a way to access the network logs so that I can verify that a specific request came in?

For example, is there a way to access the network tab in the console via Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: See this previous [thread](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/is-there-a-capturenetworktraffic-implementation-in-selenium-2-via-webdriver) for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can only do what user can do in the browser (that's the whole point).

So if user can access logs from the browser (which will have to be a service by that third party), you can do it with selenium. If not, you cannot (so your logs are safe from any lurker).